# How can I get some particular link form the links collection

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I'm using watir-webdriver have several lines of the same code shown below:

```
...
    <p class="schedule-text">
    by 
    <a href="http://www.somesite.com">MarketingClub</a> 
    in 
    <a href="http://www.somesite2.com">Marketing</a>     
    </p>
```

I need to get the first links included in p tag  and the second links included in p tag
 so using page object I've added the following code:

```
links(:followees_category, :css => "#home-followees li.animate-in ul li[data-show-id] p.schedule-text a")
```

...

```
followees_category_elements.attribute("href")
```

the last row will give me both links : http://www.somesite2.com, http://www.somesite2.com
Unfortunately, I can't indicate in css :last/:first etc.

the second link can be gotten by changing css to :

```
#home-followees li.animate-in ul li[data-show-id] p.schedule-text a + a
```

but how can I get just the first links from such blocks?
Of course, I can get both links and work with every 2nd, but maybe there is an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css `nth-of-type` pseudo class to get elements based on their index (or relative position).

For example, `a:nth-of-type(1)` can be used to return all links that are the first line of their parent:

```
links(:followees_category, :css => "p.schedule-text a:nth-of-type(1)")
```

For the second links, you can do `a:nth-of-type(2)`. Note that it is 1-based index.

```
links(:followees_category, :css => "p.schedule-text a:nth-of-type(2)")
```

For the first link, you can also do `a:first-of-type`:

```
links(:followees_category, :css => "p.schedule-text a:first-of-type")
```

If the second link is always the last link, you can also do `a:last-of-type`:

```
links(:followees_category, :css => "p.schedule-text a:last-of-type")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using css selectors like these, because they make your tests harder to read and more fragile.

But, whatever the selector is in the end, i would use Ruby's Enumerable methods to get the second links like this:

```
links.select.each_with_index {|_, i| i.odd? }
```